# Binary tree coding problems with c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, binary-tree

```
// Node
struct Node
{
    int val;
    string color;
    Node* left_child;
    Node* right_child;
};
```

Why don't the code below work?

```
Node* node = new Node();
Node* &test_node = node->left_child;
test_node = new Node();
test_node->val = 1;

test_node = test_node->left_child; // this
test_node = new Node();
test_node->val = 2;
```

why could not the **test_node** point to the parent node on mark position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not reassign a reference. 
So this statement

```
test_node = test_node->left_child;
```

just overwrites with `NULL` the previous value of the `node->left_child`.

Instead of a reference use a pointer. For example

```
Node **test_node = &node->left_child;
*test_node = new Node();
( *test_node )->val = 1;

test_node = &( *test_node )->left_child;
*test_node = new Node();
( *test_node )->val = 2;
```